# Javascript get date in format

Tags: javascript, date

I want to get today's date in the format of mm-dd-yyyy

I am using `var currentDate = new Date();
document.write(currentDate);`

I can't figure out how to format it.

I saw the examples `var currentTime = new Date(YY, mm, dd);` and `currentTime.format("mm/dd/YY");`

Both of which don't work

I finally got a properly formatted date using

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1;//January is 0!`

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd}
if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm}
var today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
document.write(today);'`
```

This seems very complex for such a simple task.

Is there a better way to get today's date in `dd/mm/yyyy`?

Comment: I'd do it manually `var d = new Date();
      var s = new String();
      s = (d.getHours()+"-"+d.getMinutes()+"-"+d.getSeconds()+"  "+d.getDate()+"-"+d.getMonth()+"-"+d.getFullYear()).toString();`. Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no better way, but instead of reinventing the wheel, you could use a library to deal with parsing and formatting dates: [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)

`<plug class="shameless">`

Or, if you find format specifiers ugly and hard to decipher, [here's a concise formatting implementation](http://blog.magnetiq.com/post/497609110/javascript-date-formatting-an-unorthodox-way) that allows you to use human-readable format specifiers (namely, [the Date instance getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Date_instances) themselves):

```
date.format("{Month:2}-{Date:2}-{FullYear}"); // mm-dd-yyyy
```

`</plug>`

Comment: Nice library, came in handy.

Comment: Another useful javascript library is momentjs.   https://momentjs.com/ You can format the date as follow. moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY')

Answer (score 18):

```
var today = new Date();

var strDate = 'Y-m-d'
  .replace('Y', today.getFullYear())
  .replace('m', today.getMonth()+1)
  .replace('d', today.getDate());
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer is no. Thats the only way to do it that I know of.
You can probably wrap into a function that you can reuse many times.

Comment: thought that may be the case. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

[date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) is what you need. For example, snippet below is to convert a date to string as Java style

```
new Date().toString('M/d/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function dateNow(splinter){
  var set = new Date(); 
  var getDate = set.getDate().toString();
  if (getDate.length == 1){ //example if 1 change to 01
   getDate = "0"+getDate;
  }
  var getMonth = (set.getMonth()+1).toString();
  if (getMonth.length == 1){
   getMonth = "0"+getMonth;
  }
  var getYear = set.getFullYear().toString();
  var dateNow = getMonth +splinter+ getDate +splinter+ getYear; //today
  return dateNow;
}
```

format this function is mm dd yyyy
and the dividing you can choice and replace if you want... for example
dateNow("/") you will get 12/12/2014

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in, but consider using this if you are already using jQuery (and if not, then you should consider that as well!)

- http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat

Answer (score -2):

```
(new Date()).format("MM-dd-yyyy")
```

N.B. month is "MM" not "mm"

Comment: Your description is not clear. Also, there are a lot of really good answers to this question already. Does your answer contribute anything? If so, please elaborate in your answer.

Answer (score -4):

```
function appendZeros(value,digits){
    var c= 1;
    initValue = value;
    for(i=0;i<digits-1;i++){
        c = c*10;
        if( initValue < c ){
            value = '0' + value;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this was meant for another question?